# Shorter nested if statements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement

I was just wondering, is there a quicker way of writing this?

```
    if (name == '' && distance == '') {
        y = 2;
    }

    else if (name == '' && distance < 1) {
        y = 2;
    }
```

I know I can just put them on the same line, but is there an easier way in which I don't have to rewrite the "name == ''" part a second time? Kind of like this:

```
    if (name == '' && (distance == '' || distance < 1)) {
        y = 2;
    }
```

In which the distance part would be evaluated first, and if one of those parameters is met, then the name == '' part would check with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, in javascript `'' < 1 === true`, so you can just do:

```
if (name == '' && distance < 1) {
    y = 2;
}
```

Comment: Also javascript uses short circuit boolean operators, so for "In which the distance part would be evaluated first, and if one of those parameters is met, then the name == ' ' part would check with it." you can swap the order like so: `if (distance < 1 && name == '')` such that distance is evaluated first, and only moves to name if distance check evaluates to true.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (name == ' ')
{
    if(distance == ' ')
    {
        y==2
    }
    else if(distance < 1)
    {
        y=2
    }

}
```

Simpler, but the intent is still obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I would write it like this:

```
if (name === '') {
    if (distance === '') {
        // do stuff
    } else {
        if (distance < 1) {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

An empty name is common for both conditions, so if it is empty, then continue to test for distance.

It is better to write a little more code if it makes it easier to understand.

Short and cryptic is often difficult to work with later on.

Comment: I agree: the shortest code is not necessarily the easiest to read or to come back later and modify. However for this very simple use case I would say that shorter is better.